# Modulo use to access different parts a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, modulo

I am trying to manipulate a two-dimensional array so that I can check if the indexes "next to" them are in a certain state. If I have an N x N grid, that looks like:

```
0 |1 |2 |3 |
4 |5 |6 |7 |
8 |9 |10|11|
12|13|14|15|
```

I want to be examine the state of index 4 and 1 before I decide how to change the state of index 0. Or if I'm examining index 5, I will check indexes 1,4,6, and 9 before I decide how the state of index 5 will change. It might help to know that I'm trying to implement Conway's game of life. Someone told me this was possible using modulo division, but I don't remember how they said to do it. I'm hoping for a general discussion of the algorithm, not a specific implementation.

Comment: thank you @dasblinkenlight for fixing up the grid

Answer (score 0):

In Conway's game of life the universe wraps around, so the squares adjacent to the top row are at the bottom, the squares adjacent to the left edge are on the right edge, and vice versa. You can use modulo division by `N` to implement this wrap around without a conditional.

Specifically, to compute the row or the column of the next cell given the row or the column of the current cell you could compute

```
int next = (current + 1) % N;
```

Computing the prior row or column is a little trickier, because subtracting `1` from `0` brings you into negative number territory; you want to avoid that. Hence, you add `N` before modulo division, like this:

```
int prior = (current - 1 + N) % N;
```

This ensures that the result is not negative.

For example, if `N` is `4`, the current row is 0, and the current column is 3, then the four adjacent cells would be

- prior, horizontally: ((0-1+4)%4, 3) = (3, 3)
- next, horizontally: ((0+1)%4, 3)    = (1, 3)
- prior, vertically: (0, (3-1+4)%4)   = (0, 2)
- next, vertically: (0, (3+1)%4)      = (0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a 2D array `state[N][N]`. We need to check all states around `state[i][j]` where `0 <= i < N` and `0 <= j < N`. Now, assume your 2D array represented by an index consisting of single number is called `single[N*N]`. Assuming `temp` is a variable in which is of the type of a single element of the 2D array. Note that if you represented the 2D array indices by a single number, instead of 2, then `i,j` would correspond to `N*i + j` if the array is stored in row major form (as given in example). Let `m` correspond to `i,j`. So, our current position in the array is `single[m]`. Note that the array in your example has a 1 based index while I'm writing here for a 0 based index.

```
int i = m / N;
int j = m % N;
```

For the state to the right of `i,j`:

```
if (j != N - 1)
    temp = single[m+1];
```

For the state to the left of `i,j`:

```
if (j > 0)
    temp = single[m-1];
```

For the state to the top of `i,j`:

```
if (i > 0)
     temp = single[m - N];
```

For the state below `i,j`:

```
if (i < N)
    temp = single[m + N];
```

EDIT: I am unfamiliar with Conway's game of life, and so have assumed that the universe does not wrap around. If the universe was to wrap around, then remove all the `if` conditions before the statements for temp.

Comment: could you explain what this is:

    N \ * i + j

specifically, the part where you use \ and then * right after it

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. I didn't notice the `N\*i + j`. I'm habitual of writing in LaTeX also, and in there to display the * character, you write it as `\*`. Have fixed it. It corresponds to N*i + j.