# Translating PseudoCode into Java with a 2D array

Tags: java

So i am working on the marking of a tile in a minesweeper assignment.

I currently am representing the minefield with a 2D array of booleans and am trying to express the following "pseudocode" into Java.

- Access coordinate (through the parameters of the method, i'll have something like `public void mark(int row, int col))`
- I'll then use if statements to determine if they have been marked already through a boolean isMarked.

My main concern is how do i express, `if isMarked==false or isMarked==true within the specific coordinates of 2D array of booleans, for example is isMarked==true at minefield[row][col]

I cant simply use minefield[row][col]==true or false as this determines if there is a mine present at the set of coordinates.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Make your best attempt to write the code and come back with specific problems back.

Answer (score 0):

> My main concern is how do i express, `if isMarked==false or isMarked==true within the specific coordinates of 2D array of booleans, for example is isMarked==true at minefield[row][col]

First, you would never see `== true/false` in production Java code. Just check the boolean there.

```
boolean[][] minefield;

if (minefield[row][col]) {
  // there is a mine
} else {
  // there is not
}
```

FWIW, you don't necessarily need a "2d array". You can represent 2 dimensions in one list. For example, `[0, 0]` [can be accessed as a 1x1 array using the length of the total list and the modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535155/2308683).